# JPA dependency issue after upgrading to Play framework 2.4

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

Ebean ORM has been pulled out from main Play core and has been introduced as an dependency in Play 2.4. great move.

But this is breaking the existing code. After following the Play [migration](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) instructions for Ebean, I get several JPA annotations errors. Upon investigating, it seems that ebean is pulling JPA 1.0 persistence API.

```
[info]   | +-org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent:4.5.3
[info]   | | +-javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm:4.6.2
[info]   |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1 (evicted by: 2.5.3)
[info]   |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3 (evicted by: 2.5.3)
[info]   |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3
[info]   |   +-javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
```

Where as in Play 2.3.9 this was not the case, it was pulling i jpa 2.0

```
[info]   | +-org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent:3.2.2
[info]   | +-org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm:3.3.4
[info]   | +-org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.3.9 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.3.9 [S]
[info]   | | +-com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
[info]   | | +-com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
```

Any pointers on excluding JPA 1.0 and depend on hibernate-jpa-2.0-api?

Comment: Guys..anybody faced similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude persistence-api from ebean dependencies.

Something like

```
("org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.6.2").exclude("javax.persistence","persistence-api")
```